# No enclosing instance of the type SuperClass is accessible in scope in inheritance

Tags: java

I studying java in academy.
When I trying to access the member in SuperClass, I see the following complier error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTyui.jpg)

> No enclosing instance of the type SuperClass is accessible in scope

```
 public class Test extends SuperClass{

        private String msg = "This msg which possess in Test";      

        protected void show(){
            System.out.println("Test.this.msg: "+Test.this.msg);
            System.out.println("this.msg in Test: "+this.msg);
            System.out.println("super.msg: "+super.msg);
            System.out.println("SuperClass.this.msg: "+SuperClass.this.msg);
        } 

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.show();       
        }

    }

class SuperClass{ 

    protected String msg = "This msg which possess in SuperClass";

}
```

Can you explain me this situation?

Comment: What do you think `SuperClass.this.msg` should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: this refers to current context ( instance ) , there is no instance of SuperClass in your Test. You can use ((SuperClass)this).msg

Comment: oh!!!!!, Thank you svasa!! now, go well!